# Can you correlate two variables when one has only 7 distinct values which repeat?

Tags: correlation, normality-assumption

I have two variables which I want to correlate. Variable “X” has only 7 distinct values which repeat for each subject tested. The other variable, variable “Y”, is the rating of the subjects to each of the levels of variable X on a scale from 0-100. All values of Y are distinct, while X has only 7 distinct values which repeat.

Can a run a correlation between X and Y? Am I violating the assumption that both variables should be random?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "run a correlation." To many readers it merely means "compute a correlation coefficient" and of course you can do that; but I suspect you might have something else in mind: maybe a regression model?  What do you really need to achieve?

Comment: You  can calculate a correlation, but with only 7 observations maybe it is not to useful. Otherwise: Your Q is too abstract, tell us what does your X, Y represent in the real world? What is your goal? ...

Comment: This is related to concert hall acoustics. X is an objective acoustic parameter, EDT, which you measure with a microphone. Y are the subjective ratings of reverberance by a subject. Only 7 stimuli (halls) where used, each one with a value of EDT. 24 subjects participated and each gave a rating of reverberance to each of the 7 halls. So there are 168 disctinct ratings of reverberance and only 7 disctinct values of EDT which repeat for each subject.. Am I violating an assumption of correlation if I obtain a correlation coefficient from these data? Thank you

Comment: What would be the point of computing such a correlation coefficient?  What do you hope to be learning about these subjects and hall acoustics?

Comment: EDT is known to be correlated with perceived reverberance. I was to measure the strength of the correlation with my data. Just that.

Comment: That seems to answer your question, then.  Since your aim is limited to that measurement, compute it.